# MVC/nInject: Implementing My Own ApplicationUserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, ninject

I'm using nInject in an MVC4 app. I would like to implement my own version of ApplicationUserManager because the scaffolded one creates a separate instance of my database context (I use nInject to inject a request scope database context into my controllers). Having a separate database context in ApplicationUserManager is causing some odd problems when manipulating the user credentials.

But I'm running into a problem creating the nInject bindings:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<CampaignDbContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<ApplicationUserManager>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
    kernel.Bind<ApplicationSignInManager>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();
}
```

The first one works fine, presumably because CampaignDbContext has a parameterless constructor.

But the second and third ones fail. ApplicationUserManager's constructor is defined as:

```
public ApplicationUserManager( CampaignDbContext context )
    : base( new UserStore<CampaignDbUser>( context ) )
{
    // Configure validation logic for usernames
    UserValidator = new UserValidator<CampaignDbUser>(this)
    {
        AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = true,
        RequireUniqueEmail = true
    };
    // etc
```

I thought that because CampaignDbContext is itself self-bound that its instance would be passed in to ApplicationUserManager's constructor. But that doesn't seem to be happening based on the error message I'm getting.

How do I configure the nInject binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ApplicationUserManager` should inherit from `UserManager<TUser>`. The constructor for `UserManager<TUser>` takes `UserStore<TUser>`, and finally the constructor for `UserStore<TUser>` takes a `DbContext`.

Instead of trying to pass in the context to `ApplicationUserManager` which should have a dependency on it in the first place, just tell Ninject how to implement `IUserStore<TUser>`:

```
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<CampaignDbContext>().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind(typeof(IUserStore<>)).To(typeof(UserStore<>)).InRequestScope();
```

Then, you can just inject `ApplicationUserManager` where it needs to go and Ninject will automatically fill it with a `UserManager<TUser>` instance that is initialized with your `CampaignDbContext`.

Comment: Thanx. I must admit I don't understand the syntax of typeof(x<>), but it works. Now to figure out why the ApplicationSignInManager keeps blowing up...

Comment: The `typeof(x<>)` is necessary to pass the type of a generic without specifying a type parameter to the generic. This allows you to bind all references of `IUserStore<T>` to `UserStore<T>`, regardless of the eventual underlying type. Otherwise, you'd have to have separate bindings for `IUserStore<Foo>`, `IUserStore<Bar>`, etc.